# zeromq subscribe and publish simultaneously

Tags: python, linux, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I am attempting to use zeromq in a debian/multiprocess situation with python.  I have several processes decoding raw data from a multitude of sensors, and publishing in zmq.  So far so good.
I have a computation process which subscribes to the raw data on zmq, and performs some computations.  It then needs to publish its answer for other processes to log and consume.  Hence my computation process needs to both subscribe AND publish in the same process.

```
import zmq
import json
context = zmq.Context()

sub = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
sub.setsockopt(zmq.RCVBUF, 0)
sub.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")

pub = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")
```

I tried the above, but no luck.  It returns an err...

```
File "socket.pyx", line 465, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.bind (zmq/core/socket.c:4749)
zmq.core.error.ZMQError: Address already in use
```

I read the documentation, google etc, but am now completely stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to bind to the same port (5000) twice which gives you the `Address already in use` error - you can only bind one socket to a port.

But the `sub` socket shouldn't `bind()`, it should do a `connect()` to some host/port that another process is publishing to (i.e. has done `bind()` on). The code should look something like:

```
sub = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
sub.setsockopt(zmq.RCVBUF, 0)
sub.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:XXXX")

pub = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:YYYY")
```

I'm guessing that you don't mean to have ports `XXXX` and `YYYY` the same, then the same process would listen to the messages it is itself publishing.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tip.  I will try it this evening.  Yes, I really did want to use a common port, which means all traffic is on the 1 port.  This makes it easier for all the other processes, as they only need to listen on the 1 port.  I guess I could use multiple ports, but this would quickly become very difficult, as I have dozens of processes, each subscribing, doing something specific, then publishing its results to multiple consumers.  Those consumers each do something else (webUI, additional processing, logging, etc)

Comment: Then make sure that you start the publisher before the subscriber in the process, otherwise the `connect()` won't be able to connect to the port.

Comment: Hi, I gave that a spin.  It looks like your suggestion of bind/socket and the order works, but my additional processes which also need to subscribe then fail to bind (as you point out, only 1 socket per port), which means I am still stuck.  maybe I should be using a pgm multicast rather than tcp socket?  I am pretty sure zmq can do this, but I cannot figure out or find how to make it happen.

Comment: When you subscribe to a port you only need to do `connect()`, never `bind()`, only the process producing values will do `bind()`. So you would need different ports for different producers. I'm not sure how multicast works in zmq, it might be the way.

Comment: Seems like zmq publishers and subscribers alike can either `bind()` or `connect()`. So it is actually valid for publishers to call `connect()` and subscribers to do `bind()`. The trick should be to make sure that only one process does the `bind()`, maybe give it a option when it starts saying it is responsible to do `bind()`?

Comment: ok, I will give it a spin.  It sounds a bit grey right now.  I can understand only 1 process can bind to port, but if it is equally valid for others to simply 'connect' then why bother to bind at all?  I attempted multicast, but pgm/epgm was not available on osx so I gave p on that option.